# includeHTML for shiny, shinyApps.IO and Dropbox

Tags: r, dropbox, shiny

Good evening,

Quick question, related to an R/shiny app, hosted on shinyApps.IO.

I'd like to have an HTML file residing on my Dropbox account, and include it into a shiny app using includeHTML. The main reason for doing that is that I have a process for my local machine to update the HTML file (which is generated using knitr), and if I could access it from shinyApps.IO, I would not have to upload it every time it is updated.

Now, an RData file on Dropbox can be read in using the following sequence of commands:

```
load("my_dropbox_credentials.rdata") # assume that file exists
file.InputData <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/SOMEDROPBOXCODE?dl=0"
data.input     <- (GET(url = file.InputData))
load(rawConnection(data.input$content))
```

This loads an RData data file from Dropbox, and it works on shinyApps.IO as well.

Now, suppose I would like to do the same thing for an HTML file, which would then be displayed using includeHTML in a shiny app. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Any advice would be appreciated,

Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates adding a dropbox html to a shiny app.  The key points are setting the `content(request, as="text")` and rendering the vector as text.

```
require(shiny)
require(httr)

request <- GET(url="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rb0cnyfiz2fgdaw/hello.html")
dropbox.html <-content(request, as="text")

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Dropbox HTML file"),
      mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("includeHTML")
        )
      ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$includeHTML <- renderText({dropbox.html})
    }
    )
  )
```

Separate ui.R and server.R

ui.R

```
require(shiny)

shinyUI = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dropbox HTML file"),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("includeHTML")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
require(shiny)
require(httr)

request <- GET(url="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rb0cnyfiz2fgdaw/hello.html")
dropbox.html <-content(request, as="text")

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$includeHTML <- renderText({dropbox.html})
})
```

Comment: Hi cdeterman - many thanks, your example works well. However, one complication: once I try to break the code into a server.R and ui.R file, I get: "ERROR: cannot open the connection".

Is there a way to keep the "2 file" structure?

Comment: @PMaier, did you have the request and dropbox.html statements in the server.R file?

Comment: cdeterman - Got it to work! I had a custom CSS file that messed things up. Thanks again, this is really cool!